# In a Select Sql Statement what is the use of having an Unlinked Table along with Linked Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

In a select query what is the practical example and uses of having Unlinked Table or Tables along with Linked Tables because the Recordset we get is just have repetition of data of the Unlinked Table columns along with the Linked Tables data.

Like if there are 3 tables:

- `tblMovies`
- `tblStudentDetails`
- `tblStudentAddress`

`tblMovies` is not linked to any of the tables. `tblStudentDetails` and `tblStudentAddress` are linked by foreign key on columns `StudentId` in both.

So can you say,

```
select tblMovies.MovieName, tblStudentDetails.StudentName, tblStudentAddress.StudentCountry
from tblStudentMovies, tblStudentDetails
inner join tblStudentAddress ON tblStudentDetails.StudentId = tblStudentAddress.StudentId
```

tblMovies:

```
MovieName
--------------
Sundance
Flashdance
```

tblStudentDetails:

```
StudentId   StudentName
------------------------
1                 Roger
2                 Sam
```

tblStudentAddress:

```
StudentId   StudentCountry
---------------------------
1                  America
2                  France
```

Then the resultset we get is,

```
Sundance     Roger   America
Flashdance   Roger   America
Sundance     Sam     France
Flashdance   Sam     France
```

Here speaking of real life scenario the Movies table and data has no relation with the other 2 student tables.

So when is such a query which just repeats the unlinked table records PRACTICALLY used in real life.

Like can you give examples of real life example tables which use such a query.

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff point taken. Thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This addresses the original version of the question.

Your query is equivalent to:

```
Select T1.MovieName, T2.StudentName, T3.StudentCountry
from T1 join
     T2
     on T1.StudentId = T2.StudentId cross join
     T3
```

If this is what you want, then you should be explicit about the `cross join`.  And the `JOIN` should be expressed on the tables actually participating in the `JOIN`.  You would do this if you wanted to join `T1` and `T2` and then the Cartesian product of that with `T3`.

The most practical use-case would be when `T3` contained exactly one row.

Comment: Dont mind but you have changed the tables completely. T1 does not have StudentId.

Comment: @BeeGees Really? Look again at the query you posted. Specifically, the ON clause `T1.StudentId = T2.StudentId`

Comment: @BeeGees Give your tables useful names and short (but still useful and not cryptic aliases) and you can help everyone avoid mistakes.

Comment: I have edited and given usefull names @SMor. Please see now. Thanx for the call to changes required.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff can you please specify a particular case example.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff thanx for your answer. You are absolutely correct. Especially your last line of table containing 1 row.